# Binding array controller/directive

Tags: angularjs, binding, controller, directive

I'm having trouble binding a controller array with a directive :

Markup :

```
<custom-directive item="tag" selectedItems="selectedArray" ng-repeat="tag in tags"></custom-directive>
```

Controller :

```
 $scope.selectedArray= [];
```

Directive :

```
scope: {
         item:"=",
         selectedItems:"="
    },
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
//Undefined
console.log($scope.selectedItems);
}
```

The binding for item works fine, what am I doing wrong for selectedItems ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause :
"selectedItems" as an attribute name doesn't work. You need to use "selected-items". "selectedItems" works fine in the directive scope.